# Database organization Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, sql-server-2008

I worked with MS SQL server which defines at database organization level the following concepts:

- instance: - independent instalation of sql server
- database: lies on an instance
- schema: logical partition of database

I have to adapt my application to an Oracle DB instance and I realized that these concepts are not the same. Can anyone explain/recommand an article about database organization in Oracle?

Comment: The quick (and "one-size-fits-all" answer: wherever you see "database" in SQL Server, substitue this for "schema" in Oracle. Each user in Oracle has one schema, so schema and user is (very) roughly equivalent in Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you! And is it possible for an instance to have multiple databases?

Comment: No. And instance and a database are basically the same thing. I urge you to read the Concepts Manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/part_inarch.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, here are the Oracle definitions:

- Home: an installation of Oracle RDBMS
- Instance: Oracle memory structures (proceses - think OS proceses)
- Database: Oracle logical/physical storage (typically OS files)
- User (Schema): a logical container for all DB objects e.g. tables
- Tablespace: a logical container for storage (most DB objects are mapped to tablespaces rather than directly to files)
- File: a physical container for storage

You can have multiple Oracle homes installed on a single OS instance (e.g. different versions of Oracle). Each home can have multiple databases. Typically 1 instance = 1 database, but in Oracle 12c you can have 1 instance = many databases, and with Oracle RAC it's multiple instances (from different nodes) pointing to the same database (which resides on a SAN). You can have as many user schemas per database as you want...

So rough translation from the SQL Server speak:

- SQL Server Instance = an amalgamation of both Oracle database as well as instance. SQL Server doesn't have RAC or multi-tenancy concepts
- SQL Server Database = sort of like Oracle tablespaces / files (in Oracle you have redo logs which are mapped to files rather than tablespaces and undo logs which are mapped to tablespaces)
- SQL Server Schema = pretty much the same as the Oracle User

Answer (score 0):

> And is it possible for an instance to have multiple databases? " - yea, it's possible in new Oracle Database 12.1 thanks to Multitenant Architecture. 
>   First of all you must read Oracle Database Concepts12c Release 1 (12.1) at this link:
>   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/toc.htm